# How to interpret a span of text as literals in regex

Tags: python, regex

I am dynamically building a regex pattern that does the following:

- `{token}` - a search string that is generated and passed to my regex function during runtime
- `page` - after the `token`, find the first occurrence of the word `page`
- number - extract the number after the word `page`

The pattern that I came up with is `{token}.*?page.*?(\d+)`, where `{token}` gets replaced by a string that is generated at runtime. This is working for the most part except when `{token}` contains special characters such as `\^$?*+()[]{}`.

**Is there anything I can wrap around `{token}` so that everything inside is taken as literals?** Right now whenever I encounter special characters I'm getting errors such as

```
re.error: unbalanced parenthesis at position 26
```

If it matters, I'm using Python. So for example:

```
import re

# The values for these two are determined at runtime
sampleText = 'These requirements result in a financial institution having to: search for certain indicia linked to an account holder (see paragraph 7.24 for a list of indicia); and/or</bbox></span></p><p text-alignment="left"><span class="text css_983095220"><bbox page="66" x="70.25" y="251.5419921875" height="10.7080078125" width="440.99853515625">request that account holders self-certify their residence status.</bbox></span></p><p text-alignment="left"><span class="text css_983095220"><bbox page="66" x="40.25" y="285.2919921875" height="109.7080078125" width="508.53515625">'
token = "7.24 for a list of indicia); and/or request that a"

# sometimes throws an error
regexResult = re.search(token+'.*?page.*?(\d+)', sampleText) 
print(regexResult)
```

Comment: [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape)

Comment: Oh I feel silly, I searched for a while but never came across that. Thank you!!

Comment: No worries - sometimes it's just a question of using the right words to search...